# Error when executing a mysql query on debian

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query that works well locally. My computer is on Windows 10 and i'm using this version of mysql : `mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

This is the query

```
SELECT conso_ht.Date_conso AS myDate, sum(conso_ht.Conso_Tranche_Jour) AS jour, sum(conso_ht.Conso_Tranche_Pointe) AS pointe, sum(conso_ht.Conso_Tranche_Nuit) AS nuit
FROM conso_ht
WHERE conso_ht.Compteur = "37178777837" 
GROUP BY year(conso_ht.Date_conso) ASC, month(conso_ht.Date_conso) ASC;
```

The mysql version of my server is `mysql  Ver 8.0.15 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

This is error i'm facing

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC, month(conso_ht.Date_conso) ASC' at line 1`

How can i solve it ??

Comment: use : **GROUP BY year(conso_ht.Date_conso) , month(conso_ht.Date_conso) ORDER BY year(conso_ht.Date_conso) ASC, month(conso_ht.Date_conso) ASC;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group by don't want ASC or DESC if you need  add an order by for this

also you can't use a different level of aggregation respect the select and the group by 
eg select a date and group by year and month

```
SELECT year(conso_ht.Date_conso)   , month(conso_ht.Date_conso)  
, sum(conso_ht.Conso_Tranche_Jour) AS jour
, sum(conso_ht.Conso_Tranche_Pointe) AS pointe
, sum(conso_ht.Conso_Tranche_Nuit) AS nuit
FROM conso_ht
WHERE conso_ht.Compteur = "37178777837" 
GROUP BY year(conso_ht.Date_conso)   , month(conso_ht.Date_conso) 
ORDER BY  year(conso_ht.Date_conso)  ASC , month(conso_ht.Date_conso)  ASC
```

or

```
SELECT conso_ht.Date_conso  AS myDate
, sum(conso_ht.Conso_Tranche_Jour) AS jour
, sum(conso_ht.Conso_Tranche_Pointe) AS pointe
, sum(conso_ht.Conso_Tranche_Nuit) AS nuit
FROM conso_ht
WHERE conso_ht.Compteur = "37178777837" 
GROUP BY conso_ht.Date_conso
ORDER BY  year(conso_ht.Date_conso)  ASC , month(conso_ht.Date_conso)  ASC
```